# How to get selected option from Apache Jelly drop down lists?

Tags: xml, jenkins, jelly

I am new to Apache Jelly and trying to implement some UI components with it.
Here, I have make a drop down list. Code is given below.

```
<f:entry name="goalType" title="Choose Goal Type" field="goalType">
        <select name="goalType">
          <option value="buildGoal">Build Goal</option>
          <option value="findBugsGoal">FindBugs goal</option>
        </select>
</f:entry>
```

Now I want to get the selected option from the drop down list and peform some operation according to the selected option.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create A field with name goalType of type String in your Backend class. Add the same field in Constructor annotated with @DataBound Constructor. The code will know that this field is from UI input of Jenkins.

If you want MultiSelect box then Create List goalType in your backend class

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
```

Comment: explanation of answer